# Problems with USB drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

When I open `Startup Disk Creator`, I see that only there is only 8kB of free space in my USB drive even though I deleted everything in it. When I click on `Erase Disk`, I then get this error

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.GLib.Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
 File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 274, in Format
part.call_set_flags_sync(boot_dos_flag, no_options, None)
GLib.Error: udisks-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error setting partition flags on /dev/sdb2: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" "set 2 boot off"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
(0)
```

I then attempted to restore the disk image as explained here: [Unknown ERROR from Startup Disk Creator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485357/unknown-error-from-startup-disk-creator)

I then entered this in the prompt: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`. I then re-tried the Startup Disk Creator and restoring the disk image, but I still get errors

When I try `gparted`, it gives this warning as soon as it opens:

```
The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes
```

When I then right-click on the partition and click `new`, it says

```
No partition table found on device /dev/sdb
A partition table is required before partitions can be added.
To create a new partition table choose the menu item:
Device --> Create Partition Table.
```

EDIT: If I click `ignore`, I see 4 partitions:

```
/dev/sdb1, File System: unknown, label: Ubuntu-Server
unallocated, File System: unallocated
/dev/sdb2, File System: fat16, Mount Point: /media/Ubuntu-Server
unallocated, File System: unallocated
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this help? [Unable to delete usb drive partitions block size error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/675649/unable-to-delete-usb-drive-partitions-block-size-error)

Comment: I click the Ignore button when using GParted and it complains about the block size. From there I'm stilll able to delete/create new partitions on USB's

Comment: @owen, no that link didn't help. I just typed `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=2048 count=32` and tried Startup Disk Creator again, and got the same error

Comment: @grannzsez, see my EDIT in the OP

Comment: Partition is unformatted!...open gparted select usb from drop down menu....delete the partitions and create new one primary. Partition with ntfs format..let me know further..(select rebuild MBR option first...to recreate MBR table)

Comment: I was only allowed to delete 1 partition: the one at `dev/sdb1`. It won't let me create a new one: `It is not possible to create more than 1 primary partition`

Comment: Use mini tool partition wizard on windows to recreate partition... hope that helps